# Create a function with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, function

I am very new on the forum and also with AngularJS.

I am trying to send a request to a REST server. I used this function

```js
$scope.submitForm = function() {
  var url = 'http://localhost:8080/Server/config/start';

  var request = $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    params: {
      name: 'test'
    }
  });

  request.success(
    function() {
      //alert('it succeeded');
    }
  );

  request.error(
    function() {
      // alert('it didnt work');
    }
  );

};
```

The code is not working properly on the server side because of some serialization stuff. I found a post on the forum that suggests using this function instead

```js
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  transformRequest: function(obj) {
    var str = [];
    for (var p in obj)
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    return str.join("&");
  },
  data: {
    username: $scope.userName,
    password: $scope.password
  }
}).success(function() {});
```

I am not sure how to use this function with my code, I tried this code

```js
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/Server/config/start';

    var request = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj)
          str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
      },
      data: {
        name: 'test'
      }
    }).success(function() {});
```

but I get an error due to the `});` . Can someone help me to format and fix the code?

Comment: what is the server side expecting - form data or raw data?

Comment: Just add a closing curly brace to close the `$scope.submitForm` function

Comment: I think form data. Not json. I am using @FormParam on jersey.

Comment: I tried to add t before to create the post... I didn't succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
  var url = 'http://localhost:8080/Server/config/start';

  var request = $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
      var str = [];
      for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      return str.join("&");
    },
    data: {name: 'test'}}).success(function () {});
} // you need a '}' here.
```

also you can try the post method of $http this way.

```
$http.post('url', data)
     .success(function(data, status, headers) { //success callback })
     .error(function(data, status, headers) { //error callback });
```